# Collating Average Data over a Time Interval for X Days/Weeks/Etc

Tags: sql, amazon-timestream

I've got an example table that holds data with a date and a value.

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 | 3 |
| 1/2/22 | 5 |
| 2/5/22 | 6 |

What I want is to allow users to select a time interval for the average and a time interval for the returned data. So something like:

Input: Avg per Month, from 1/1/22 to 3/1/22

Output:

| Date-Range | Average |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 - 2/1/22 | 4 |
| 2/1/22 - 3/1/22 | 6 |

My understanding would be I'd first need to select dates from the total time interval:

```
SELECT value FROM myTable WHERE Date >= INPUT_LOW_DATE AND Date <= INPUT_HIGH_DATE
```

That returns me that data between it, but I'm not sure how to then group the data by a date range. This is easy with loops, but my SQL syntax knowledge isn't that great. Is there something like:

```
for (i = INPUT_LOW_DATE; i = i + INPUT_TIME_INTERVAL; i < INPUT_HIGH_DATE) {
    WITH data as (
        SELECT 
            AVG(value) FROM myTable WHERE Date >= i AND Date <= i + INPUT_TIME_INTERVAL as avg,
            -- Not sure how string concatenation works in sql, apologies
            "" + i - INPUT_TIME_INTERVAL + " to " + i as interval,
    )
}
```

And then I can display the created `data` table?

Thanks for any help!

edit: A user pointed out that I forgot to add the tools being used. The data is held in AWS TimeStream and being displayed in Grafana

edit2: I may be a bit naive regarding Time Series databases versus Relational Databases, but they appear to at least work with mostly the same syntax (though have different functions and optimization). Regardless, I believe I was able to achieve somewhat of my needs through:

```
SELECT value, BIN(time, 1d) AS binned_timestamp,
    ROUND(AVG(value), 2) AS avg_value
FROM myTable
WHERE measure_name = 'myMeasureName'
    AND time > ago(7d)
GROUP BY avg_value, BIN(time,1d)
ORDER BY binned_timestamp ASC
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: @DannySlor AWS TimeStream

Comment: Did you investigate the create_timeseries function? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/timeseries-specific-constructs.views.html